# How to create dynamic powershell query?

Tags: powershell, redgate

I have a Powershell query to get the backup of my database. But i need to have the backup the data with different names like DATABASEBACKUP_CURRENTDATE. How can i achieve this?

```
./RedGate.SQLAzureBackupCommandLine.exe /as: AzureServerNAME/ad: AzureDatabaseName    /au:AzureUserName /ap:AzurePassword /cc /s /ls:. /ld:LOCALDATABASENAME_CURRENTDATE /dl /v /ba
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, build a string that contains the current date:

```
$backupName = $("Backup-{0}" -f [DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Then call RedGate and use the date string as a parameter:

```
./RedGate.SQLAzureBackupCommandLine.exe /as: AzureServerNAME /ad: AzureDatabaseName /au:AzureUserName /ap:AzurePassword /cc /s /ls:. /ld:$backupName /dl /v /ba
```

Ed: Copypaste/markup messed with brackets and colons, fixed 'em.

Comment: When i am trying to create the string i am getting error on Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"). You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-f' operator.
At line:1 char:32
+ $backupName = $("Backup-{0}" -f <<<<  Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression

Answer (score 0):

To get a string constructed with the current date, you can simply do:

```
"DATABASEBACKUP_{0:MM-dd-yyyy}" -f [DateTime]::Now
```

It will give something like `DATABASEBACKUP_01-12-2012`. You can use that as arguments as needed

Answer (score 0):

Throwing in another solution...

"DATABASEBACKUP_$(Get-Date -Format MM-dd-yyyy)"